# How to remove QPushButton focus rectangle using stylesheets

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qpushbutton

I have a QPushButton and when it is on focus it has a rectangle on it that I want to remove. Here some screenshot:

Normal button:

[image]

Focused button:

[image]

I have tried to add something (`backgroundcolor`, `text-decoration`, etc)

```css
QPushButton:focus
```

But, it keeps on highlighting.

QPushButton stylesheet:

```css
QPushButton
{
    color: #b1b1b1;
    background-color: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #565656, stop: 0.1 #525252, stop: 0.5 #4e4e4e, stop: 0.9 #4a4a4a, stop: 1 #464646);
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #1e1e1e;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 6;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

QPushButton:pressed
{
    background-color: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #2d2d2d, stop: 0.1 #2b2b2b, stop: 0.5 #292929, stop: 0.9 #282828, stop: 1 #252525);
}
   
QPushButton:hover
{
    border: 2px solid QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #ffa02f, stop: 1 #d7801a);
}

QPushButton:focus {
    /*background-color: red;*/
}
```

PS. I'm on Ubuntu 12.04, with Qt 4.8, and I'm using this [stylesheet](http://www.yasinuludag.com/darkorange.stylesheet).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The highlighted rectangle may be the `QStyle::PE_FrameFocusRect` styling. The only way to get rid of it is by implementing a custom style. Fortunately, Qt provides a way to implement just a proxy, which uses another style in the general case. For the focus rectangle you'd implement:

```
class Style_tweaks : public QProxyStyle
{
    public:

        void drawPrimitive(PrimitiveElement element, const QStyleOption *option,
                           QPainter *painter, const QWidget *widget) const
        {
            /* do not draw focus rectangles - this permits modern styling */
            if (element == QStyle::PE_FrameFocusRect)
                return;

            QProxyStyle::drawPrimitive(element, option, painter, widget);
        }
};

qApp->setStyle(new Style_tweaks);
```

Comment: impressive.. it works.. I thought it was an Ubuntu problem (see my own answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/17297035/433685 ).. but let me ask one thing more: how to change this behavior and instead of return (drawing nothing) underline the text?

Comment: `QPushButton:hover { text-decoration: underline; }` qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html Otherwise, you really have to paint the underline, but with this I have no experience.

Comment: I also wanted to underline QPushButtons on hover like this but it does not work. The text is not underlined.

Comment: `QPushButton {  outline: none; }` is the way to remove the focus rect ***without writing code***. It is an undocumented property.

Comment: @user362515 that sounds pretty neat. Does the property exist in Qt4 and Qt5?

Comment: @chelmuth yes, it wirks both for qt4 and qt5.

Comment: @user362515 it's documented by the community: [qt4 help page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html)

Comment: Generally after using this proxy general stylesheets (`setStyleSheet(...)` methods) won't work without any additional tweaks...

Comment: @avtomaton Indeed. And vice versa: if the stylesheet keeps working, the proxy won't anymore: https://marcmutz.wordpress.com/private-practice/whats-in-a-proxy-style/

Answer (score 11):

```css
QPushButton:focus {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Where should I put this code? I'd like the same effect for all buttons.

Comment: @Sigur you can set a default application stylesheet with [`QApplication.setStyleSheet()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#styleSheet-prop). Be aware that if you do set an global stylesheet, [selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) are *mandatory*.

Answer (score 6):

One more alternative (works on Windows and Ubuntu), for simplicity I use solid colors:

```cpp
ui->pushButton->setStyleSheet(
    "QPushButton { background-color: #0188cc; color: #ffffff; outline: none }"
);
```

Note: `"outline: none"` property — it removes focus rectangle from the button.

And one more related tip for checkable buttons: by default checked buttons are drawn with a dot pattern, not a solid color as I expected for:

```css
QPushButton:checked { background-color: #0188cc; color: #ffffff; }
```

I added `"border: none"` to the button stylesheet:

```css
QPushButton:checked {  background-color: #0188cc; color: #ffffff; border: none }
```

And the dotted pattern disappeared! Now my checked buttons are clean, as I expected with solid background style.

Answer (score 3):

I ran this snippet of code both on Windows 7 (Qt5) and on Ubuntu 12 (Qt4.8).  There are no problems with it:

```
QFile file("style.css");
if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
  QString data = file.readAll();

  // "this" is the derived QMainWindow class
  this->setStyleSheet(data);
}
```

And alternatively...

```
ui->pushButton->setStyleSheet("QPushButton"
                              "{"
                              "color: #b1b1b1;"
                              "background-color: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #565656, stop: 0.1 #525252, stop: 0.5 #4e4e4e, stop: 0.9 #4a4a4a, stop: 1 #464646);"
                              "border-width: 1px;"
                              "border-color: #1e1e1e;"
                              "border-style: solid;"
                              "border-radius: 6;"
                              "padding: 3px;"
                              "font-size: 12px;"
                              "padding-left: 5px;"
                              "padding-right: 5px;"
                              "}"
                              "QPushButton:pressed"
                              "{"
                              "background-color: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #2d2d2d, stop: 0.1 #2b2b2b, stop: 0.5 #292929, stop: 0.9 #282828, stop: 1 #252525);"
                              "}"
                              "QPushButton:hover"
                              "{"
                              "border: 2px solid QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #ffa02f, stop: 1 #d7801a);"
                              "}"
                              );

qDebug() << ui->pushButton->styleSheet();
```

Comment: after clicking on that button you don't have the light-orange rect I have in the screenshot?? Also with the complete css file I linked setted up in QApplication??

Comment: If I copy your code and apply the style ONLY to the instance of QPushButton I have the same problem.. this let me think that could be some Ubuntu preferences..

Comment: Yeap, both that code snippet and loading the entire css file worked on Windows and Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Huytard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280056/qt-css-decoration-on-focus/17280556#17280556) I have found out that is not a Qt CSS problem but it is the normal behavior of my Ubuntu Appearance setting to add an Orange rect on focused buttons.

The theme Ambiance is the default theme in Ubuntu 12.04 and it has the graphical behavior of enhancing focused elements with an orange inner rectangle.

If I change the theme the effect I posted about and I thought was QT CSS problem is gone away. So.. it is not a QT CSS problem but Ubuntu. If someone is interested in that.. http://askubuntu.com is full of information about changing the main theme color.