# How to change the focus color (highlight color) of QPushButton

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qpushbutton, qpalette

How do I change the focus color of a pushbutton as here:

[image]

I also changed the background color of the button, and the palette, but still no change occurred.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QT - CSS: decoration on focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280056/qt-css-decoration-on-focus)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use stylesheets:

```css
QPushButton:focus:pressed{ background-color: some_colour; }
QPushButton:focus{ background-color: some_other_colour; }
```

You can either use Qt Creator to add the styles to your button, or load them inside your code by calling `setStyleSheet("...")` on your button.