# How to show dotted focus rect on QToolButton

Tags: qt, qwidget

I have a QToolButton

```
QToolButton* button = new QToolButton();
button->setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon);
button->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
button->setIcon(myIcon);
button->setText("Test");
```

I want it to have dotted focus rect around it when doing tab focus but it does not show . By default it should show the focus rect but it does not .Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: I tested your code and it does show focus rect. Maybe you should check other part of your code. Did you add some stylesheet to change it or other actions?

Comment: I added background color and border to none in stylesheets

Comment: Because of that stylesheets, you are experiencing this behavior of `button`. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280056/qt-css-decoration-on-focus

Comment: I tried setting outline to QToolButton:focus but it did not work