# pyQt5 QPushButton with no border

Tags: python, linux, pyqt5

I have a problem with QPushbutton under Linux
Under Windows 10,  I've made a couple of buttons like this one:

```
 self.playbutton = QPushButton("", self)
 self.playbutton.setGeometry(1, 2, 35, 27)
 self.playbutton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color : rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"
                               "background-image : url(images/play.png); border: 0px}"
                               "QPushButton::hover {background-image : url(images/play_over.png);}"
                              )
 self.playbutton.clicked.connect(self.play)
```

The buttons appear correctly under linux but the button which have the focus show a grey border like this:

[image]

Can someone help me with this

Comment: What if you use `border: none; outline: none;` for the default selector stylesheet? (Please write a comment when you edit a post, otherwise we won't get notified about it)

Comment: outline: none; do the job, thank you again

Comment: Please accept the duplicate request based on this post: [QT - CSS: decoration on focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280056/qt-css-decoration-on-focus)